# MySql Multiple Update, each column own expression?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

i use this query to update 3 Tables, but i have to check the updated field for every update table before.  Normally i use a Single Update for every Table.

```
UPDATE tab1   
  left 
  join tab2 
    on tab2.Col1 = tab1.id   
  left 
  join tab3 
    on tab3.Col1 = tab1.id    
  left 
  join tab4 
    on tab4.id = tab2.extid 
    or tab4.id = tab3.persid    
   SET tab1.col3 = 1
     , tab1.col4 = CURDATE()
     , tab2.col3 = 1
     , tab3.col4 = CURDATE()
     , tab2.col4 = CURDATE()
     , tab3.col3 = 1    
 Where tab1.col2 = 'Deutschland' 
    or tab4.land != 'de'
```

Example:

```
SET tab1.col3=1, if(tab1.col4=NULL)tab1.col4=CURDATE(),if(tab2.col4=NULL)tab2.col4=CURDATE()
```

Comment: Your UPDATE must cause an ambiguous reference error.

Comment: Sorry, i changed Tablenames and add the tables for update, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` which will return `CURDATE()` if the column is `NULL`, or the existing value of the column if it is `NOT NULL`:

```
SET tab1.col3 = 1
 , tab1.col4 = COALESCE(tab1.col4, CURDATE())
 , tab2.col3 = 1
 , tab3.col4 = COALESCE(tab3.col4, CURDATE())
 , tab2.col4 = COALESCE(tab2.col4, CURDATE())
 , tab3.col3 = 1
```